# Cron job not working for Whenever gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cron

I have an application that contains a bunch of tasks, and every 3 minutes I want to run a cron job that sends a mail for some test. I'm using the whenever gem but it doesn't seem to be running at all.Any ideas?

config/schedule.rb

```
every 3.minutes do
  runner "MailerClass.some_method"
end
```

MailerClass.rb

```
def some_method
  mail(:to => "some email", :cc => 'some email', :subject => "Regular Email by rake task #{Time.now.strftime("%H : %m")}", :from => "default_sender@udk.com") do |format|
  end
end
```

What I have Tried after modifing config/schedule.rb are,

```
whenever --update-crontab --set environment=development
sudo service cron restart
```

When I run
    crontab -l
  this is the output

```
0,3,6,9,12,15,18,21,24,27,30,33,36,39,42,45,48,51,54,57 * * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'cd /home/my_app && script/rails runner -e development '\''MailerClass.some_method'\'' >> log/notification.log 2>&1'
```

I have checked the log. The problem is 
    script/rails: line 6: syntax error near unexpected token `('
    script/rails: line 6:`APP_PATH = File.expand_path('../../config/application',  **FILE**)'

I am not getting this. I am new to rails. Thats why may be :(.

Any Solution!!!

Answer (score 0):

Based on your updated info i am updaing my answer
Remove last single quote form end of parenthesis form this line `APP_PATH = File.expand_path('../../config/application', FILE)'`

Comment: Thanks, Sorry It is not in Model , It is in Mailer class. it is my writing mistake.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are forgetting to actually send the email

Instead of

```
MailerClass.some_method
```

try

```
MailerClass.some_method.deliver
```

Comment: Thank you, I have also tried this. Still not solving the problem.I checked the log. Here is the problem found. But I am not getting this. I am new to rails, That's why may be :)                            ascript/rails: line 6: syntax error near unexpected token `('
script/rails: line 6: `APP_PATH = File.expand_path('../../config/application',  __FILE__)'